# Search by name and surname

Tags: python, django

I have a search bar in template

```
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search...">
```

In Model I have two seperate properties name and surname

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

In views.py I have logic like this

```
search = self.request.GET.get("search", None)
if search:
    Person.objects.filter(Q(name=search) | Q(surname=search))
```

I want to filter with name surname or both of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the bitwise or (`|`) operator to construct a logical or between two conditions, so:

```
search = self.request.GET.get('search')
if search:
    Person.objects.filter(Q(name=search) | Q(surname=search))
```

or you can define the connector between the two conditions with:

```
if search:
    Person.objects.filter(Q(name=search, surname=search, _connector=Q.OR))
```

You can also concatenate the two fields with [**`Concat`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#concat) and then filter with:

```
from django.db.models import CharField, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

if search:
    Person.objects.annotate(
        full_name=Concat('name', Value(' '), 'surname', output_field=CharField())
    ).filter(Q(name=search, surname=search, full_name=search, _connector=Q.OR))
```

But it is not a good idea to search with such queries: if one adds an extra space, or writes the names as surname followed by the name, this will not work.

If you want to do a full text search you need search technology. For example [*PostgreSQL's full text engine*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch.html) and work with a [**`SearchQuery`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#searchquery) or a [**`SearchQuery`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#searchvector).

Another way to search is with search technology like *Solr*, *ElasticSearch*, etc. and then you can use [**`django-haystack`** [readthedocs.io]](https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/master/) to make calls to the search engine.

Comment: Yep I did that, still not working with name + surname

Comment: @maca: what do you mean with "not working"?

Comment: When I write for example Willem Onsem, it is not filtering that person, it works only with only name and only surname

Comment: wel in case you want to search on that you need to "concatenate" the `name` and `surname` (with a space in between). But that is not advisable. If you want to search on keywords, you should use searching technology like *Solr* or *ElasticSearch*, and talk to it with `django-haystack` for example https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/master/ or for example the PostgreSQL searchvector/search query: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/postgres/search/

Comment: I must to concatenate these two fields, but I don't know how

Comment: @maca: see edit, but I would strongly recommend, *not* to work with such concat, a small extra character, or word reordering will result in bad filtering.